# How do I rename C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, rename

I need to rename this command because it interferes with ImageMagick. I tried to run this in an administrator console:

```
C:\Users\Chloe>rename C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe C:\Windows\System32\convertNTFS.exe
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\Users\Chloe>rename C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe convertNTFS.exe
Access is denied.
```

I also tried to rename it in Explorer. Nothing works!

Comment: Take owner of the file, right click on the executable, and rename it.  Why don't you just put the ImageMagick path before Windows/System32 in the path variable

Comment: That doesn't work. Now it says "You need permission from xps\Chloe...". The package is installed with [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/imagemagick.tool) and is in `chocolatey\bin`.

Comment: Now I can't change the owner back to `TrustedInstaller`. That user/name/account doesn't exist.

Comment: I assumed you understood the risks of changing the owner, and your desire, to accomplish what you wanted was defiant?  You will have to reset the ACL on the file

Comment: How do you reset ACL?

Answer (score 5):

It is usually not a good idea to rename system files (or change their NTFS permissions, after the next OS-Update this may be reversed back). Ideally contact your Software vendor (for ImageMagick) to request that they don't name their files with the same name as Windows system files.

A workaround hack, is to tell Windows to execute a different program when you are running `convert.exe`

Run something like this:

```
reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\convert.exe" /v Debugger /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Program Files\ImageMagic\convert.exe" /f
```

I haven't tested this and I am not sure whether it works if the target has the same name as the source, but it is worth a try.

And you better remember you've done this if you even want to use to convert.exe to convert your file systems.

Another option is to put the ImageMagic folder into the path before %systemroot%.

I would really try to fix the application rather than changing system files.

Comment: an `sfc /scannow` will also revert any change system files

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc That command gives the error `Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service.`

Comment: @Chloe http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-resource-protection-could-not-start-the-repair-service anyway as Peter said, changing any system file is risky because it can be reverted at any time

Comment: cd into the ImageMagick folder and run `convert` also works, or just provide the full path to the exe in the command line. But the easiest way is putting the path befor %systemroot%

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I suggested that solution but it was ignored

Comment: another solution is to rename ImageMagick's convert.exe

Answer (score 1):

To rename a file through Command Prompt, you can use the RENAME or REN command.

For example:

```
rename convert.exe new-convert.exe
```

However, before making this change, please copy a version of it to protect it in case something wrong.

```
copy convert.exe convert-copy.exe
```

Besides, if you have changed the ownership of convert.exe and now want to switch back to TrustedInstaller, then I would recommend searching for `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller` instead of `TrustedInstaller`

Take a look at [this guide](http://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-restore-trustedinstaller-as-default-owner-of-a-file-or-folder-in-windows/)

Comment: The first part was useless because I already said I tried that, but the second part worked, so -1 + 1.

Comment: Well! Glad that it helped you. I don't care much about the point. Just want to help :)