# unix find command on cmder.exe in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, unix, find, terminal-emulator

I installed [cmder](http://cmder.net/) shell emulator for Windows.

Works fine but I can't use Unix's find command. Apparently when I type:

```
'find .'
```

in the terminal it tries to use the Windows' FIND and output this error:

```
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

I'd really like to use find, any hint on how to get it working?

Comment: You would need to make whichever directory `find` is in appear before `C:\Windows\System32` (where Windows' find lives) in the `PATH` environment variable. This is generally considered not a great idea to do globally as it tends to confuse other programs that expect a standard Windows environment. Rather, you should see if you can set a startup script in Cmder, and make the script do something like `set PATH=C:\path\to\folder\with\unix\find;%PATH%`

Comment: I don't know `cmder`, but in Linux/Unix `which -a find` will show all programs which could execute with the find command. Identify the Unix `find`. Then use its full path, or re-arrange the order of `PATH` directories, or set an alias, if `cmder` supports this; you could also rename the Windows `find.exe` to `wfind.exe`. If it emulates `bash`, then you can use the in-built `type -a find`.

Comment: @AFH [renaming any Windows system files is risky because Windows updates or `sfc /scannow` can revert it](https://superuser.com/a/1208043/241386)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I rename C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/1208018/how-do-i-rename-c-windows-system32-convert-exe)

Comment: @AFH `which -a find` returns `/c/WINDOWS/system32/find 
/usr/bin/find`. Unfortunately, though, running `/usr/bin/find` yields `The system cannot find the path specified.`. It seems the actual windows-style path is needed here. Running `type` launches the windows `type`, and it appears `cmder` does not provide the unix-like version.

Comment: @simlev - As you say, Cygwin or (if on Win10) WSL may be a better bet, though it is less easy to call native Windows programs, which may not suit the questioner.

Comment: You may wish to move `%git_install_root%` where the new `PATH` is constructed in `init.bat`, see https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/37

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simplest solution is to create an alias to the `find` executable within the `cmder` installation folder:

```
λ which find
/c/WINDOWS/system32/find
λ find --help
FIND: FIND: Parameter format not correct
λ alias find=C:\Files\Programs\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\bin\find.exe $*
λ find --help
Usage: /usr/bin/find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

May I suggest you also try out [Cygwin](https://cygwin.org) where, among other things, `find` works out of the box. That is what I used to ascertain the location of the `cmder`-supplied `find.exe`.

Kudos to [@Bob](https://superuser.com/users/117590/bob) and [@AFH](https://superuser.com/users/327367/afh) for their insightful comments, and to [@Lưu Vĩnh Phúc](https://superuser.com/users/241386/l%C6%B0u-v%C4%A9nh-ph%C3%BAc) for suggesting another dead-simple solution:

> rename the *nix `find` to another name like `fnd.exe`

This might actually be preferrable over creating an alias, because `cmder` aliases don't work in Windows 10 unless `Use legacy console` is selected in `cmd` properties (see [how to](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/enable-use-legacy-console-for-command-prompt-in-windows-10.html) do it).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Seems the best way to go. I normally use cygwin when on windows but for working reasons I am forced to cmder right now. I will try this asap!

Comment: @Heisenbug `cmder` has the obvious advantage of being portable and not needing installation to be performed by a privileged user.

Comment: you can also simply rename the *nix `find` to another name like `fnd.exe`

Comment: I renamed the unix version, to avoid modifying windows native stuff. But thanks, what I was really missing was the folder where those commands where stored and your answer helped me.

Comment: Isn't gnu find normally called gfind on non-gnu systems?

Comment: Don't let it confuse you that after you successfully setup your `find` alias, `λ which find` still responds with `/c/windows/system32/find`.   `λ which find` cares about your path, not your cmder alias.

Answer (score 3):

`Cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\bin` is added to the PATH by `Cmder\vendor\init.bat`. Unfortunately, it's added at the *end* of the PATH, so Windows's find.exe is found first.

Fortunately, it's easy to fix. Just add this line inside `Cmder\config\user-profile.cmd`:

`set "PATH=%GIT_INSTALL_ROOT%\usr\bin;%PATH%"`

Comment: Jerem is referring to the windows find here:
`C:\Windows\System32\find.exe`.  In the System variables path it looks like `%SystemRoot%\system32`, usually towards the top.

Answer (score 1):

*An addition to previous answers:*

A) I recommend using the **`CMDER_ROOT` variable**, accessible either as `%CMDER_ROOT%` or `$CMDER_ROOT` depending on environment (*see .sh example and note about `%GIT_INSTALL_ROOT%` below*).

B) You can define your **aliases in Cmder's `user_aliases.cmd`** like so:

```
[...]

;=
fnd=%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\bin\find.exe $*
```

to be added into `%CMDER_ROOT%\config\user_aliases.cmd`.

C) For those who need to use `find` in their cross-OS scripts, this is a workaround: In your `foo.sh` to be run either on Windows and Linux use:

```
if [ "$(command -v find)" = "/c/WINDOWS/system32/find" ]; then
    # Windows
    FIND_CMD="$CMDER_ROOT\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\bin\find.exe"
else
    FIND_CMD="find"
fi


# Your command here, for example:
$FIND_CMD my-folder -type f -not -iname 'exclude-me.md'
```

---

*Note: `%GIT_INSTALL_ROOT%` mentioned above may be different than what you want, for example in my case:*

```
λ echo %CMDER_ROOT%
C:\Dev\Programs\Cmder

λ echo %GIT_INSTALL_ROOT%
C:\Program Files\Git
```

*Note 2: While previous answers are correct in their explanation and proposed solutions, in my case more details were needed – which I have tried to put into my answer.*

Answer (score 0):

I have installed smartgit in windows

Then I add C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\git\bin (my smartgit folder) into path environment

press win+r enter bash. in the bash shell you can use find command.
in Cmder you also can type bash to use it